# I am trying to deploy my express app to vercel but gives me error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deployment, vercel

Error: File /vercel/path1/node_modules/simple-update-notifier/node_modules/semver/preload.js does not exist.

[The build logs :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJorC.png)

Tried removing the node modules and lock file and then publishing. Also tried switching between npm and yarn

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

please check if you have **semver** inside your package.json

Comment: no semver in my package.json